# showing status with large file transfers via netcat/nc

Tags: linux, tar, file-transfer, transfer, netcat

I am using `nc`/`netcat` to transfer a large tar stream. Is there a way for either side to show some kind of status? Like how much has been transferred and/or the speed while it is transferring?

On the receiving end:

```
nc -l 9000 > data.tar
```

On the sending end:

```
tar cf - -C /path/to/data files | nc -N [target server] 9000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At its simplest, you could use `pv` - the pipe viewer:

```
tar cf - . | pv -b | nc -N [target server] 9000
```

If you look in the man-page, you can see how to *"guesstimate"* the size of the tar-file which potentially allows `pv` to calculate an estimated time of arrival.